# What is the "remote" object in alfresco aikau?

Tags: javascript, dojo, alfresco, aikau

[Here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/aikau-tutorials-crud-create.html) is example about alfersco CRUD service. They use:

```
remote.call("/slingshot/datalists/lists/site/test/dataLists");
```

To make http request. I have examing `aikau` sources but it contains only calls like `remote.connect` or `remote.call`, also defined aikau modules do not contains explicit dependecies from this object. So what is `remote` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a "request" module to GET/POST/PUT/DELETE to external URLS.

It has the following methods :

> .post(uri, body)—POSTs content to the given URI
>
> .post(uri, body,contentType)—POSTs content of the specified type to the given URI
>
> .get(uri)—GETs content from the given URI
>
> .put(uri, body)—PUTs content to the given URI
>
> .put(uri, body, contentType)— PUTs content of the specified type to the given URI
>
> .delete(uri)—Invokes a URI as a DELETE request

[See the full documentation here](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/surf-remote-api.html)

Comment: Strage, that this object mentioned in surf documentation, not aikau.

Comment: That's because it is an artefact of Surf and not Aikau... Aikau is not dependent upon it, and there are many other non-Aikau implementations on Surf that use it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand somewhat on the answer provided by xShirase... the remote object is specifically related to accessing the REST APIs that are available on the Alfresco Repository that the instance of Share (or any other Surf-based application such as a standalone Aikau client) is configured to work against.

Surf handles all of the authentication so that once authentication has been provided (i.e the user has logged in) it does not need to be provided again and this also ensures that only APIs available to that user can be be accessed.

The key thing to understand is that this is a request from one server-side application to another and may even be from one server to another. It is not a client to server call.

Comment: The REST API that the remote object calls is on the Alfresco Repository by default but that is not a requirement. You can configure Surf to hit any endpoint, not just Alfresco.